# Initialisation list with this pointer

Tags: c++, constructor

Got confused here. Even on passing `this` in the initialization list, the program is being compiled and run successfully.
I had the impression that on passing `this` here the compiler should give some error as the object had not been created here.

The output of both the `cout`s is the same; i.e they hold the same address.

I know this is not correct programming methodology but whats exactly is happening here ?

```
    class foo
    {
            public:
            foo():myself( this ) {}
            foo * myself;
    };


    int main()
    {
            foo f;
            cout<<f.myself<<endl;   
            cout<<&f<<endl;
            return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though the object isn't fully initialized yet, its address is known and can be assigned to a pointer.

Although this idiom isn't at all common, I could see it being used for initialization of a linked list for example.